# Divisibility problem: $ \frac{3^{m}}{2^{n} - 3^r} $

Tags: divisibility

> Is divisible a power of 3 for a difference of powers of 2 and 3? That
>   is, can result, this division, in an integer? $$ \frac{3^{m}}{2^{n} -
> 3^r} $$ where $n,m,r$ natural number.

**Edit**: $n>r$, $r=m+1$.

Comment: Trivial cases $$2^2-3^1=1, 2^3-3^2=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We need $\displaystyle 2^n-3^r=\pm3^s$ where $s\le m$

$\displaystyle 2^n=3^r\pm3^s$

**Case** $1:$ Taking the $+$ sign, $2^n=3^r+3^s=3^{r-s}(3^s+1)$ (WLOG $r\ge s$)

As $(2,3)=1,$ we need $3^{r-s}=1\iff r=s$ and $2^n=3^r+1$

**Case** $2:$ Taking the $-$ sign, $2^n=3^r-3^s=3^{r-s}(3^s-1)$ (we need $r\ge s$)

Like the previous case, we must have $r=s\implies 2^n=3^r-1$

See [Catalan's Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConjecture.html)

Comment: What does this mean? That $\frac{3^{m}}{2^{n} -3^r}$, $n>r$, $r=m+1$ is satisfied only for $r=s$?

Comment: @Lely, As explained in the answer $r=s$ is required for all $n,r\ge0$